# Rollup resolve plugin and transitive dependencies

Tags: javascript, reactjs, rollupjs

I am using `rollup` and `rollup-plugin-node-resolve` to build a React library.

In my library I have a dependency on e.g. `json-diff` & `jsoneditor` and I want to bundle it with library so that consumers of my library don't have to install them manually.

So I've included `json-diff` in `resolve` using `only` option. However when I did that, `rollup` informs me about other dependencies that are not handled - transitive dependencies of `json-diff`:

> (!) Unresolved dependencies
>   https://rollupjs.org/guide/en#warning-treating-module-as-external-dependency
>   difflib (imported by node_modules\json-diff\lib\index.js, 
>   commonjs-external:difflib) cli-color (imported by
>   node_modules\json-diff\lib\colorize.js,  commonjs-external:cli-color)

I wonder, am I doing something wrong? Is this correct approach of resolving? I would like to include `json-diff` and its dependencies. Do I have to list all transitive dependencies? For `json-diff` this is not so cumbersome, but I have other like `jsoneditor`, and there the list is very long.

Here's my `rollup.config.js`:

```
import resolve from 'rollup-plugin-node-resolve';
import babel from 'rollup-plugin-babel';
import commonjs from 'rollup-plugin-commonjs';
import json from 'rollup-plugin-json';
import pkg from './package.json';

import postcss from 'rollup-plugin-postcss';

export default {
  input: 'index.js',
  external: ['react', 'prop-types', 'uwr-react-widgets', 'json-diff', 'jsoneditor'],
  output: [{ file: pkg.module, format: 'esm' }],
  plugins: [
    resolve({
      only: [
        'ajv',
        'ajv-errors',
        'ajv-keywords',
        'enumify',
        'lodash-es',
        'moment-timezone',
        'bigdecimal',
        'fast-json-stable-stringify',
        'fast-deep-equal',
        'uri-js',
        'json-schema-traverse',
        'moment',
      ],
    }),
    babel({
      exclude: 'node_modules/**',
    }),
    commonjs({ extensions: ['.js', '.jsx'] }),
    json(),
    postcss({
      autoModules: true,
      namedExports: true,
      modules: true,
      extensions: ['.css', '.less'],
    }),
  ],
};
```

Comment: Isn’t the whole point of node that you *don’t* have to bundle your dependencies?

Comment: I'm not sure I get your point. This is a browser lib. React apps are installing this library and use their components. I have a component that depends on `json-diff` & `jsoneditor` so I would like to ship it along with the library bundle.

Comment: If someone’s developing a React app, they’ll probably have a build system. Most (if not all) modern JS build systems (including Rollup as you’ve seen) have npm-resolution capabilities. If you publish your library as an npm module, you can let *that* build system resolve its dependencies to prevent duplicates

Comment: Ok. So what you're saying that I should put `json-diff` & `jsoneditor` as `peerDependency` and put it inside `external` section of rollup config and let client app install these dependencies?

Comment: that's alarming, I'd expect all `json-diff` & `jsoneditor` dependencies to be bundled as well, what does your `rollup-plugin-node-resolve` config look like?

Comment: I've added whole config to my question. Thx

Comment: Ohhh, perhaps `rollup-plugin-node-resolve` compare all dependencies against the value specified in `only` array? Have you tried just remove `only` altogether (I've actually never used it), or add `difflib` and `cli-color` to the `only` array?